# Assign data between n persons in python

Tags: python, distribution

I want to assign the data in equal proportion between various people in python automatically. The names should appear in the first column 'Name' automatically.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please be specific with what you mean by 'automatically'. If I don't get the result you wanted wrong then it should be like this:

```
df['Name'] = ["Person 1","Person 2","Person 3",...]
```

The length of 'Name' column rows should be the same with the other.